# Package and run Angular2 RC.0 like the previous beta aggregated module

Tags: javascript, angular

Since I upgraded to Angular2 RC.0, all the modules are now loaded individually (600 HTTP requests on the application loading) which is very long and almost unusable. The beta17 loads all the modules at once (or at least one file for each core, http, rxjs...).

I have followed the official quickstart guide for beta and RC.

Could you tell me how to use the same mechanism as the beta or what the new mechanism is to use aggregate modules with the RC.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the answer from @A-Hsiao and adding rxjs dependency, I have sucessfully combine all js files into one minified file. The following node script must be executed.

```
    var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');

var packages = {
    'rxjs': {main: 'Rx.js'}
};
var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
];

packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = {main: 'index.js'};
});
packageNames.push('rxjs');
var builder = new Builder({
    baseURL: '/node_modules',
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    packages: packages
});

packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
    builder.bundle(pkgName, 'build/assets/' + pkgName + '.js')
        .then(function () {
            console.log(pkgName + ' Build complete');
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(pkgName + ' Build error');
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

All the generated file can be combined and minified. Then the following systemjs.config.js must be imported after the bundled file.

```
(function (global) {
    var map = {
        'app': 'app'
    };

    var packages = {
        'app': {main: 'main.js'},
        'rxjs': {main: 'Rx.js'}
    };

    var packageNames = [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router-deprecated'
    ];

    packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = {main: 'index.js'};
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages,
        defaultJSExtensions: true
    };

    if (global.filterSystemConfig) {
        global.filterSystemConfig(config);
    }

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

Comment: Angular CLI should now be used.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue, and resolved by 'systemjs-builder'. but havn't test detailly. for you as a reference. https://github.com/A-hsien/Angular2-systemjs-builder

thx for comment from @Gaurav.

following code will package '@angular' by each folder under '@angular'.
just save them to a whateverthename.js file.

```
var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');

var packages = {};
var packageNames = [
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/router-deprecated',
  '@angular/upgrade',
];

packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
  packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js' };
});

var builder = new Builder({
  baseURL: '/node_modules',
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  packages: packages
});

packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
  builder.bundle(pkgName, 'assets/'+ pkgName+'.js')
    .then(function() {
      console.log(pkgName+'Build complete');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(pkgName+'Build error');
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

then execute  the command `node whateverthename.js`.
modeues will be build to assets folder.

Comment: Angular2 packager seems working but I cannot handle rxjs library. Do you also have a solution to package it in the same way ?